# timespan difference value always positive

Tags: c#, timespan

i want to convert the timespan diff value always positive

My code is here :

```
TimeSpan lateaftertime = new TimeSpan();
lateaftertime = lateafter - Convert.ToDateTime(intime);
```

i want to get the result of lateaftertime always positive..
please help me..

Comment: Note that a difference between 2 **TimeOnly** values is different-always positive and can be confusing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73039686/timespan-calculation-is-different-between-timeonly-and-datetime#comment129031324_73039686

Answer (score 102):

You can use `lateaftertime.Duration()` to get a non-negative span.

Comment: No need for such thing, just use `Duration()` that would give an absolute `TimeSpan`

Comment: @V4Vendetta:  I never knew that.  Learn something every day.  That's a much nicer approach.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Instead of changing your answer, you shoul've asked @V4Vendetta to post his and get the deserved recognition. This is totally my personal opinion, but I think it's unfair that you get the upvotes for his answer.

Comment: V4Vendetta has always been free to post his own answer.  If he'd posted it, I wouldn't have changed my answer.

Answer (score 6):

You could use Math.Abs():

```
        lateaftertime = new TimeSpan(Math.Abs(lateaftertime.Ticks));
```

User V4Vendetta made the right call in a comment though.  Use the TimeSpan.Duration property, it always returns the absolute value.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I'll assume you're using C# because it looks that way.

The `-` operator on the `TimeSpan` class has been overloaded, so all you need to do is prefix your calculation with `-` as you would if you were performing the conversion on an integer. Here is some code that you can run in a Console App:

```
var inTime = "19-Jan-2012 21:00";
var lateAfter = Convert.ToDateTime("19-Jan-2012 20:00");
TimeSpan lateAfterTime = lateAfter - Convert.ToDateTime(inTime);

var positiveLateAfterTime =
    lateAfterTime < TimeSpan.Zero
    ?
    -lateAfterTime
    :
    lateAfterTime;

Console.WriteLine(positiveLateAfterTime.ToString());
```