# TimeSpan difference from negative value to positive conversion

Tags: c#, .net, timespan

```
TimeSpan Earlybeforetime = new TimeSpan();
Earlybeforetime = earlybefore.Subtract(Convert.ToDateTime(outtime);
```

Sometimes it returns a negative value. How do I convert the value to be always positive?

Comment: possible duplicate of [timespan difference value always positive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922435/timespan-difference-value-always-positive)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could use `Negate()` to change the negative value to positive

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby.aspx)

> If the date and time of the current instance is earlier than value,
>   the method returns a TimeSpan object that represents a negative time
>   span. That is, the value of all of its non-zero properties (such as
>   Days or Ticks) is negative.

So you could call the Negate method depending on which value is greater and obtain a positive `Timespan`

Say we have `startDate` and `endDate` (*endDate is greater than startDate*), so when we do 
`startDate.Subtract(endDate)` we would get a negative `TimeSpan`. So based on this check you could convert the negative value. So if your outtime is ahead of earlybefore it would give you a negative TimeSpan

**EDIT**

Please check `Duration()` of the `TimeSpan` this should give you the **absolute value always**

`Earlybeforetime.Duration()`

Comment: i can't understand please explain me or give some example code here

Comment: sometimes i got positive value also suppose i ll use Negate() means that positive value change to negative.That's no need for me. i just want all return value is positive.

Comment: @user1065029 Expanded a bit more, hope this helps you

Comment: I have one doubt How can i get the first and last date for a month .. My input is jan or feb . i want the output start date 01-01-2012 and end date 31-01-2012 or start date 01-02-2012 and end date 29-02-2012. How can i get the above output form a month

Comment: Well i think first day wuld be easy since it would be 1, based on that you can use add days and use `DateTime.DaysInMonth` and arrive at the last day

Answer (score 11):

Negative values are returned when yours Earlybeforetime is **earlier** that outtime.
if you want to have absolute "distance" between two points in time, you can use TimeSpan.Duration method, e.g:

```
TimeSpan first = TimeSpan.FromDays(5);
TimeSpan second = TimeSpan.FromDays(15);
TimeSpan final = first.Subtract(second).Duration();


Console.WriteLine(final);
```

this method will return absolute TimeSpan value.

Answer (score 3):

```
var startTime = new TimeSpan(6, 0, 0); // 6:00 AM
var endTime = new TimeSpan(5, 30, 0); // 5:30 AM 
var hours24 = new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0);
var difference = endTime.Subtract(startTime); // (-00:30:00)
difference = (difference.Duration() != difference) ? hours24.Subtract(difference.Duration()) : difference; // (23:30:00)
```

can also add difference between the dates if we compare two different dates times the 24 hours `new TimeSpan(24 * days, 0, 0)`

Answer (score 1):

posativeSpan = new TimeSpan(negativeSpan.Ticks * -1);